# Is there a way for a cell value to be updated based multiple cells all in different sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have four different cells in four different sheets that can all be different values via a drop down. Is there a way for a cell in a fifth sheet to be the value of the latest changed cell?

> ```
> cell1val   cell2val   cell3val    cell4val         cell5val
>  1           1         1           1                 1
>  1           1         1           2                 2  
>  3           1         1           2                 3
> ```

Above is a quick example of the desired outcome. cell5val which is in a different sheet is whatever the latest updated value is of any of the other four cells.

Comment: Yes, put a `Worksheet_Change` event in the first 4 worksheets that writes the value of `Target` into the 5ᵗʰ worksheet on a change. So sheet 5 will always show the latest changed value of any of the 4 sheets.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, this should solve me issue perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, put a `Worksheet_Change` event in the first 4 worksheets that writes the value of Target into the 5ᵗʰ worksheet on a change. So sheet 5 will always show the latest changed value of any of the 4 sheets.

Put something like the following in each of the 4 sheets.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim AffectedRng As Range
    Set AffectedRng = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A1:A10")) 'this is the range you want to observe

    If Not AffectedRng Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Sheet5").Range(AffectedRng.Address).Value = AffectedRng.Value
    End If

End Sub
```